# How do I create a global 'Hotkey' window for Alacritty?

Tags: terminal, macos, alacritty

I've been migrating from iTerm2 to Alacritty, and the feature I miss most is the global hotkey window. I've attempted to replicate this behavior using AppleScript, but to no avail. What's the best approach to duplicate iTerm2's hotkey window behavior in Alacritty?

Answer (score 0):

You edit the .config/alacritty/alacritty.toml (in newest versions, previously was .yaml) file.

Alacritty reloads that life, so you can always test.

Alacritty is by um "culture" not a program that comes with graphical settings dialog.